# How Can I Insert X Carriage Returns after Every row with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a text document with 365 consecutive lines (rows). How can I add 13 lines in between each line (row) using Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way (assuming Windows-style line endings of "\r\n" rather than "\n") might be:

1. Press Ctrl+H to open find/replace dialog.
2. Put this in 'Find what': \r\n
3. Put this in 'Replace with': \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
4. Select 'Extended' as the 'Search Mode'.
5. Press 'Replace All'.

Note that there are 14 "\r\n"s in step 3 because one of them is the line ending that's being replaced.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Really going to have to find resources for using the functionalities of Notepad++